# Is there a more efficient way to obtain variance of lot's of columns than dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, summarize

I have a data.frame that is >250,000 columns and 200 rows, so around 50 million individual values. I am trying to get a breakdown of the variance of the columns in order to select the columns with the most variance.

I am using dplyr as follows:

```
df %>% summarise_if(is.numeric, var)
```

It has been running on my imac with 16gb of RAM for about 8 hours now.

Is there a way top allocate more resources to the call, or a more efficient way to summarise the variance across columns?

Comment: 8 hours seems too much, even for dplyr. Something sounds like it's gone very wrong.

Comment: Yes it's very odd and as you can see below converting to long format worked in about 20 seconds...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try using `data.table` which is usually faster.

```
library(data.table)

cols <- names(Filter(is.numeric, df))
setDT(df)
df[, lapply(.SD, var), .SDcols = cols]
```

Another approach you can try is getting the data in long format.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  select(where(is.numeric)) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = everything()) %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  summarise(var_value = var(value))
```

but I agree with @Daniel V that it is worth checking the data as 8 hours is way too much time to perform this calculation.

Comment: The dplyr version worked in 20 seconds. I never considered that wide format would take so much longer than long format...

Answer (score 2):

I bet that selecting the columns first, then calculating the variance, will be a lot faster:

```
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(runif(5e7), nrow = 200, ncol = 250000))

df_subset <- df[,sapply(df, is.numeric)]
sapply(df_subset, var)
```

The code above runs on my machine in about a second, and that's calculating the variance on every single column because they're all numeric in my example.

Comment: Thanks, the code: 

df_subset <- df[,sapply(df, is.numeric)]

gives back a list of logical TRUE or FALSE if cols that are numeric.

Which means the sapply does not work to return a data.frame of variance?

Comment: I'm surprised that's the result you get when you run it. The `sapply` does indeed return a logical vector, but then it's used within the `[` call so that what *should* be returned is the subset of columns where the `sapply` returned TRUE. It also works on my laptop, so I'm not sure what the difference there could be.

Answer (score 1):

Very wide data.frames are quite inefficient.  I think converting to a matrix and using `matrixStats::colVars()` would be the fastest.